# Fetch and store a column values from sqlite in android(java) array

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, fetch

I want to store the values of a particular column in the array, As I am a fresher I don't know how to do this. I am getting values from sqlite as

```
1
2
123
432
3
5
```

I want to store these values in string array. Please tell me I am not finding any appropriate example by googling about this.. thanx in advance.

```
public void fun(String query){
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    try{
        String[] arr = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        if(cursor != null){
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
                    arr[i] = cursor.getString(0).trim();

                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

    }finally{
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Here query is

```
SELECT <COLUMN_NAME> FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE <CONDITION>;
```

I think I am doing it wrong please correct my errors...

Comment: Put your code how you getting these values from array, so we can fill these in array for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider using `rawQuery` is a bad habit, try to avoid this(except in extreme cases)

Try as follows to solve your problem, hope this will help you:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllStringValues() {
    ArrayList<String> yourStringValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor result = db.query(true, YOUR_TABLE,
            new String[] { YOUR_COLUMN_NAME }, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            yourStringValues.add(result.getString(result
                    .getColumnIndex(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME)));
        } while (result.moveToNext());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return yourStringValues;
}
```

Use this method in **YourCustomDBManager** class. consider **NotePad** example of android developers sites example programmers guide for getting better concept. It will help you to learn how to deal with SQLite. I am also new in Android, but I learned everything about SQLite from *NotePad* example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<String> vecInt = new Vector<String>; // you can use any datatype <int><float>

cursor.moveToFirst();
for(i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
{
      vecInt.add(cursor.getString(COLUMN_NUM));// if you are using datatype other then string then need to convert here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] val = new int[cursor.getCount()]; // integer array
for(int i= 0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
     val[i] = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
```

Comment: I have put my code doing somehow like this but not getting exact answer.. please check